# MySql wont start

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-12.04

'Hi I have a pretty recent install of MySql on DigitalOcean.

And for some reason I cannot get MySql to start.

```
141003 07:25:17 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
141003 07:28:53 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
141003  7:28:53 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
141003  7:28:53 [Warning] The syntax '--log-slow-queries' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use '--slow-query-log'/'--slow-query-log-file' instead.
141003  7:28:53 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
141003  7:28:53 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
/usr/sbin/mysqld: Table 'plugin' is read only
141003  7:28:53 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
141003  7:28:53 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
141003  7:28:53 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
141003  7:28:53 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
141003  7:28:53 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
/usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/tmp/ib2UuPLv' (Errcode: 13)
141003  7:28:53  InnoDB: Error: unable to create temporary file; errno: 13
141003  7:28:53 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
141003  7:28:53 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
/usr/sbin/mysqld: File '/var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log' not found (Errcode: 13)
141003  7:28:53 [ERROR] Could not use /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log for logging (error 13). Turning logging off for the whole duration of the MySQL server process. To turn it on again: fix the cause, shutdown the MySQL server and restart it.
141003  7:28:53 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
141003  7:28:53 [ERROR] Aborting

141003  7:28:53 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

I have tried mysqlupgrade
but that doesn't work as mysql is not running.

Answer (score 5):

It's not "for some reason", the errors are pretty evident of what's going on. You have permission issues, as MySQL can't read the InnoDB logfiles or create temporary files.

Either mysql is set up with the wrong username or someone has gone haywire with chmod/chown on large parts of the filesystem.

Comment: I have tried to fix this a few ways. I tried to chown mysql /tmp but that didnt fix anything, would you recommend a few commands I could run to fix the permissions?

Comment: /tmp should have 777 permissions

Comment: @KazimierasAliulis 1777 it should have the sticky bit set.